# Android insert date SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, date, records

in this method I insert multiple records with start date and end date. 
That works fine, but for example if I choose the start date as 31/01/2014 and 31/07/2014 as the end date I choose. records of the following months will be placed always on the 28th because he takes on the last day of the month. How can I avoid this problem?

```
GregorianCalendar dateAndTime =(GregorianCalendar)GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
GregorianCalendar dateAndTime1 =(GregorianCalendar)GregorianCalendar.getInstance();

public void InsRecords(){
SQLiteDatabase db = mHelper.getWritableDatabase();
ContentValues cv =newContentValues();

if(mRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId()== R.id.radio){
    SimpleDateFormat sdf1 =newSimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

    while(dateAndTime.compareTo(dateAndTime1)<=0){
         String strDate = sdf1.format(dateAndTime.getTime());
            dateAndTime.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);           

             cv.put(eTable.DATE, strDate);
             db.insert(eTable.TABLE_NAME,null, cv);

    }
    db.close();
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "avoid this problem"? How do you want the follow-up dates calculated? In your example, do you want them at the end of the month, like 28/02/2014, 31/03/2014, 30/04/2014...? Or every 30 days?

Comment: I modified the method that works, but if I choose as the starting date 31/01 and the end date as 31/07, when it arrives in February or months that have 30 days are added to the record with the 28th, because the Calendar, in this case, takes as a reference the last day of the month. Instead I would like that if you have chosen the day 31, when the month has 30 or 28 must insert the record with that day. I hope I explained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure if I'm understanding completely, but I think you mean: if the starting date is the last day of the month, then the following dates should be as well. If so, then I believe this might work for you:

```
public void InsRecords()
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = mHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv = newContentValues();

    if (mRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.radio)
    {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

        boolean lastDay = dateAndTime.get(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) == dateAndTime.getActualMaximum(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        while (dateAndTime.compareTo(dateAndTime1) <= 0)
        {
            String strDate = sdf1.format(dateAndTime.getTime());            
            dateAndTime.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);

            if (lastDay)
            {
                dateAndTime.set(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dateAndTime.getActualMaximum(GregorianCalendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
            }

            cv.put(eTable.DATE, strDate);
            db.insert(eTable.TABLE_NAME, null, cv);

        }
        db.close();
    }
}
```

For your example, this will give the following:

```
2014-01-31
2014-02-28
2014-03-31
2014-04-30
2014-05-31
2014-06-30
2014-07-31
```

Comment: To me it always seemed getting last day of month requires less code and is more readable if you get the 1st of the following month, then back up a day.

Comment: @RobP, that's a nifty idea I hadn't thought of. I'm not sure that would take less code, unless the OP means that s/he is dealing with _only_ the last day of the month. Dunno. Feel free to post an answer. As I noted, I'm not sure I'm understanding fully.